# How to add Class active on Click in Navbar

Tags: jquery, css

I have some tabs in my page, when I click a tab it refresh the page and removes the active class.

I have tried the following code.

```
$(".nav-item").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: check if you have <a> tag with href in navbar

Comment: You should build this in the code that renders the navbar on page load instead.

Comment: @sohan bairwa In HTML add `.nav-item .active class` by default to the first tab.

Comment: When you refresh the page, all the code added by js was removed. so you have to check in another way how to get active tab when the page is loaded

Comment: add your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
   $active_menu = $this->uri->segment(1);    
   $active_submenu = $this->uri->segment(2);    
  ?>

 <li class="nav-item <?php echo ($active_menu == 'quiz'?'active':''); ?>">
 <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>quiz/">Quiz</a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna assume that `.nav-item` is an anchor link to which you've assigned the click event, hence the page refresh. You need to disable its default operation

```
$(".nav-item").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".nav-item").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Alternatively, you can achieve it like so

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-item"></a>
```

Also, if you want to have the tab selected on page load too, you need to call its function on, well page load.

**Edit:** Extending @Bram Verstraten's comment, you can use query strings for the link's `href` and set the active class on page load extracting it, like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $queryStirng = location.search;
  //the above fetches the query string from the URL. For e.g., ?tab2 from http://localhost?tab2

  $(".nav-item" + $queryStirng).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Your code is work But i want to go on click another page

Comment: Then why are you concerned what happens on this page after you redirect?

Comment: This can only be done on page load. Not when clicking on the link. Put something in the query string like: `?page=2` and on page load you can set the correct link to active.

Comment: @Nimsrules <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>report/report_course/">Course wise</a>